# How should we handle questions that repeat frequent misconceptions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed, canonical

I've come over [this (stated as) newbie question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723734/how-are-variable-names-handled-when-using-functions) here recently.

It's a frequently observable misconception in questions for a number of programming languages, that scoped/local variable/parameter symbolic names are thought to be related in a way.

I've been initiating closure quite well, but changed my mind now. The question as is now isn't really *too broad*, but just states an easy to answer misconception.

I've been trying to bang this question in shape, to look a bit more canonical, and tried to answer.
Though the question's state seems to be hopelessly doomed, and I attempted to setup a canonical answer for this kind of misconception (at least for c++) no matter of it's current score.

**What else (besides asking here, voting to reopen) can I do to, make this fly?**

If anyone already has a handy canonical for this question, please mark it as duplicate there.

If anyone feels invited, edit the question, give more answers or edit the existing one as appropriate.

---

Since the question in question was deleted meanwhile, a snapshot for the mere mortals

[image]
[image]

Comment: So, you are asking if there is any canonical for variable identity, touching such concepts as `scope`, `lifetime` and all relevant types of forward-`declaration`, right?

Comment: @Deduplicator What I'm observing is, that newbies always confuse variable/symbol names,- beyond any scope given -, to match what they think it does (including shadowed variables).

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, finally I'm asking if such canonical already exists (at least for [tag:c++]), or at least, if we can pick-up a completely OT question to make it a canonical :-P ...

Comment: @remyabel Didn't see `void main()` for the particular case, did you? But even if so, I#d like to dupe hammer such kind of questions as soon I see them :-P ...

Comment: Voted to re-open, just to have a canonical *duplicate* to point others to. Not going to up vote it though, it's still a horrible question. "I do not really understand the `return` part", jeez.

Comment: @Jongware _"I do not really understand the return part"_ I even tried to answer this appropriately.

Comment: Boah, @RobertHarvey short cut decided to completely delete it :-P ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Seems you have to make your own, thorough self-answered one. At lest Robert just deleted the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator _"Seems you have to make your own, thorough self-answered one."_ Yeah, seems so. I'm going to consider that. May be not today (-nite) though (yawn) ;-) ...

Comment: This question almost seems so fundamental as to close as duplicate of the C++ book list (probably with a comment saying why).

Answer (score 8):

Close it as a duplicate of the canonical question/answer pair that you've already created for this purpose.

**Example:** [What would the evaluation order of x = x++ + ++x; be?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2367969/102937)

If you don't have a canonical post to close it as a duplicate of, or it isn't a qualified duplicate of a canonical question, then handle it in the usual fashion (i.e. close it if it's unclear, too broad, etc).

If it's a decent question, and no canonical exists for it, make it the new canonical, and close future questions as duplicates of it.

Comment: So as @Deduplicator already suggested (and I more or less accepted so), I have to create my own canonical Q&A a priori, but there's merely no chance to pick up a incoming one, and bang in shape for becoming a well accepted canonical?

Comment: Why not?  I already said you could do that in my answer.

Comment: _"If it's a decent question"_ So my part would have been making it one, and I obviously failed, since you decided to delete it :-( ...
Though I'd appreciate some hints how this question could have been made a _decent one_ beyond my edits (trying not to vandalize the question).

Comment: Taking a cursory look at the question and answer, it seems that the OP merely lacks some fundamental knowledge.  Only a book, training, or more self-learning fixes that.

Comment: I've been observing that particular kind of confusion regarding variable/parameter names and return values a lot of times (especially for c/c++ language). Though you're correct, this kind of stuff is usually covered by the basic lectures, it's a common misconception thinking these are related through naming somehow (because of misleading sample code maybe).

Comment: _"Close it as a duplicate of the canonical question/answer pair that you've already created for this purpose."_ To be clear about this: I don't have one, but I want to make that question fitting for a canonical.